# Difference between ad-hoc and wifi hotspots

Tags: ieee-802.11, ad-hoc-wireless

Reason why I'm asking this is because I want to know why mobile phones cannot discover ad-hoc networks created by laptops or PCs?

Comment: Funny, my mobile phone can and so can my tablet. There might be a setting for "Do not join ad-hoc networks" or something like that. Ah, or you might have to assign a static IP address to a device joining an ad-hoc network because the device creating the network might not be handing out IP addresses. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4327536?tstart=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wi-Fi has two working modes - IBSS (ad-hoc) and BSS (infrastructure mode). The main difference between these two modes is access-point. This kind of device is available only in infrastructure mode.

1. In ad-hoc mode when station A wants to transmit a frame to station B it just transmits this frame to station B.
2. In infrastructure mode, station A at first transmits this frame to access-point, and access point retransmits this frame to station B.

And why your mobile phone can't connect with ad-hoc networks? I believe here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100928/how-to-connect-android-wifi-to-adhoc-wifi (at least for Android).